# PHP files which I have include doesn't appear in php file

Tags: php, html, include

**ANSWER:**  Was a problem with web hosting.

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
        <meta name="description" lang="en" content="Test Website " /> 
        <meta name="author" content=""> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="wrapper">
            <?php include('includes/topHeader.php'); ?>
            <?php include('includes/leftSide.php'); ?>
            <?php include('includes/middleSide.php'); ?>
            <?php include('includes/rightSide.php'); ?>
        </section>

        <?php include('includes/foot.php'); ?>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

question the other php files not appear in the main page?

to create it I have use this website
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-create-php-website-template/

**Update**
View Source shows:

```
<section id="wrapper">

<!--?php include('../includes/topHeader.php'); ?-->
<!--?php include('../includes/leftSide.php'); ?-->
<!--?php include('../includes/middleSide.php'); ?-->
<!--?php include('../includes/rightSide.php'); ?-->

</section>

<!--?php include('../includes/foot.php'); ?-->
```

Comment: Swap the `include` to `require`. I imagine that the files aren't in the directory you think they're in.

Comment: Have edit post, have a look please

Comment: What do your included files contain? Can you post an example?

Comment: You have a closing "</section>" tag without an opening.

Comment: @Timber232 is there `<section id="wrapper">`

Comment: @Steve there is but that is closed before the foot.php is included.

Comment: @Steve There is another closing </section> beside the closing </body>

Comment: delete it and still not working
Have edit the post, have a look plase

Comment: Maybe your PHP code isn't being executed at all. What do you get if you view source in the browser? do you see the PHP tags?

Comment: nop, simply I can see everythink from this html file same as without php files

Comment: In your browser open up View Source. Are the other files actually there, but not visible? Then you have malformed HTML and need to fix that. Does a file not appear, or does your page just stop at some point? Then you have an error in your PHP and need to fix that. Regardless, Andrew's suggestion to use `require` rather than `include` is a good one: if you need this content on your page, then logically you ought to `require` it.

Comment: In the source the php files covered in comments like <!-- php code -->

Comment: Are you using ".php" or ".html" as the file extension for this HTML?

Comment: Maybe your PHP error reporting is turned off by default. Overwrite with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1').`

Comment: @Herbert .php using for this one

Comment: Interesting. Will you please paste the output into a Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) and add the link here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J2vMr/1/

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: I mean what you see using View Source in your browser.

Comment: ou ok, page converted to this
http://jsfiddle.net/K7sQn/

Comment: Did you add `<?php ini_set('display_errors', '1') ?>` at the very beginning as suggested by @Timber232? I also don't fully understand what you mean about the _php files covered in comments_. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I show  in above code what i mean by comments,  and where I should add this code < sorry for stupid question.

Comment: Hmm, how did you run this code? Did you right click the file and open in a browser? or are you hosting this on a server? Or are you running this on XAMMP or any other Apache server?

Comment: Strange. Something is commenting out your PHP code. Can execute something simple like `<?php echo "Hello world!" ?>`?

Comment: @Herbert nop((( can't(

Comment: Ohh! another thing I should point out, your title tag is missing an ">". `<title</title>`. That could be it.

Comment: You may need to contact hosting24.com for support. I've never encountered a problem where PHP code is automatically commented out. You should also edit your question to show what you're seeing in "view source". As it stands, someone who could potentially help would have to wade through all these comments and follow a link to see it.

Comment: Can delete the post, they not explain anything, just said you can try it now (((

Comment: Now working perfectly

Comment: So it was an issue with the web host? Anyway. I'm glad you got it worked out.

Comment: Someone else could have this problem in the future, so it would be helpful to them if you post your own answer describing what you did to fix your problem. You can also accept your own answer. That way anyone else who comes across the same problem doesn't have to read all the comments to find out that it was a hosting problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `include` function right, so please make sure that:

- Files you are trying to include really exists, you can test with [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function
- You don't have any fatal errors somewhere in the files that stops the execution of your program (you can check error log)
- Your markup is well formatted (in some cases when code is not formated correctly browsers cannot render the page correctly)

Answer (score 0):

On a quick note apart from what was already suggested. Try

```
<?php include('../includes/topHeader.php'); ?>
<?php include('../includes/leftSide.php'); ?>
<?php include('../includes/middleSide.php'); ?>
<?php include('../includes/rightSide.php'); ?>
```

I say this with an assumption that the include folder resides above the current file in the folder structure.

Comment: Judging by the tutorial that Denis linked to, that's not the folder structure.

Comment: opps sorry I didnt check the tutorial.

Comment: No worries. It's a good thought, anyway, and usually an effective sanity-check in situations like this.

Comment: Try debugging it using firebug. Check the Net TAB and resolve the path accordingly.

Comment: Don't forget to revert back to `<?php include('includes/topHeader.php'); ?>` before testing any other suggestions. I noticed the code at http://jsfiddle.net/K7sQn/ is still using `<?php include('../includes/topHeader.php'); ?>`

Comment: I have delete "../" part of the path

Comment: did u try it with '../'. And Make sure the folder include as the correct access rights.

Comment: Something is adding comment tags to the PHP tags. It's not the folder structure.